# Set default ListView

Tags: android

Is there any way to change the `ListView` in a `SherlockListFragment` from defaulting to `R.id.list`? e.g. I have a custom list that overrides the default `ListView` in xml (list) that is defined as being below a linear layout. How do I make it so that `setListAdapter` will use this `ListView` instead of the default android `ListView`?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_view_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toggleLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toggleLL" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public class ProblemFragment extends SherlockListFragment
{
    private SeparatedListAdapter list;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getSherlockActivity().setContentView(R.layout.apps_layout);

        list = new SeparatedListAdapter(this.getSherlockActivity(), new Layout(R.layout.separated_list_adapter_two_text, R.id.two_text_title, R.id.two_text_desc));

        setListAdapter(list); //Sets the list to the default list, not the overwritten list specified in the xml
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you can use this.

Comment: Issue is that it doesn't work. setListAdapter simply ignores the mylist in XML. If I replace it with `ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);`, `lv.setAdapter(list);`, and `setListShown(true);`, THEN it works for mylist. However, this also introduces a number of other bugs that I would rather not have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your layout XML to use `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

ListActivity and ListFragment rely on the ListView having the id `android.R.id.list`, which is publicly exposed in the SDK (and accessible in XML via `@android:id/list`). If you look at the docs for either of those classes, both mention that using your own layout requires that you give your ListView this id for it to work properly.

Comment: I've changed it to that, but it still ignores the `layout_below` value I set. I'm using `setListAdapter` now, and it overwrites the default list.

Comment: First, you should not use `wrap_content` for the height of a ListView.  Set it to `0dp`, keep the `layout_below` and also add `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Alternatively, you could just use a vertical LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout. Keep the inner LinearLayout the same and give the ListView `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` instead of using RelativeLayout attributes.